# Text lowered and cutoff in android but not ios - react native

Tags: react-native

The text should look like this
[IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMKpz.jpg)

But on Android it looks like this:
[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUpDS.png)

The code for the styling of the text and container is:

```
text: {
  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
  fontSize: 40,
  width: 250,
  height: 40,
  textAlignVertical: 'center',
  textAlign: 'center',
},
container: {
  backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
  width: 250,
  height: 55,
  margin: 12.5,
  borderRadius: 10,
  justifyContent: 'center'
}
```

and the components:

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.container}
  onPress={_ => this.navigation.push('Join')} >
  <Text style={styles.text}>Join</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.container}
  onPress={_ => this.navigation.push('Create')} >
  <Text style={styles.text}>Create</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `styles` with this :

```
text: {
    fontFamily: 'Roboto',
    fontSize: 40,
    textAlignVertical: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
    margin: 12.5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: 250,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `styles` to below -

```
text: {
  fontFamily: 'Roboto',
  fontSize: 40,
  textAlignVertical: 'center',
  textAlign: 'center',
},
container: {
  backgroundColor: '#DDDDDD',
  width: 250,
  minHeight: 55,
  margin: 12.5,
  borderRadius: 10,
  justifyContent: 'center'
  alignItems: 'center',
  alignSelf: 'center',
}
```